Found multiple publish output files with the same relative path. while publising ASP.NET Core 6 project
In .NET Core 6 where when publishing with Web Deploy via Visual Studio 2022, I get the following error:

Error: found multiple publish output files with the same relative path:

There is no issues when building, just publishing.
I have 7 ASP.NET Core 6 projects, 6 of which are referenced in one project.
I am aware that this is expected functionality in .NET Core 6 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/sdk/6.0/duplicate-files-in-output). I am aware of the ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles property.
I kept this property then the files are published.
But when I host the project in Azure App service Linux environment, the application is not running as expected.
I added this ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles property in the .csproj file:
<PropertyGroup>
     <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
</PropertyGroup>

But the application is not working, do I need to configure any, I referenced 6 projects in one project like this
var channelStartup = new SF.Notification.Delivery.API.ChannelReslvr.Startup(Configuration, hostingEnvironment);
channelStartup.ConfigureLocalServices(services);

var emailStartup = new SF.Notification.Delivery.API.EmailDelivery.Startup(Configuration, hostingEnvironment);
emailStartup.ConfigureLocalServices(services);

var messageRslvrStartup = new SF.Notification.Delivery.API.MessageReslvr.Startup(Configuration, hostingEnvironment);
messageRslvrStartup.ConfigureLocalServices(services);


Hi Hemanth, could you kindly check the solution2 in this link and give it a try.

Is your issue resolved ?
